# Scala, Casbah: Compilation errors. How to instatiate object from external libary?

Tags: scala, casbah, objectinstantiation

I am trying to write function that writes data to MongoDB using Casbah toolkit:

```
  import com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern
      import ...

  def saveRecord(rec: MongoDBObject) {
    mongoColl.insert(rec, WriteConcern)
  }
```

Casbah defines WriteConcern as a Scala object. I get the following errors:

```
No implicit view available from Object => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject.  

not enough arguments for method insert: (implicit dbObjView: Object => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject, implicit concern: com.mongodb.WriteConcern, implicit encoder: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBEncoder)com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.WriteResult. Unspecified value parameter dbObjView.
```

Also when I try simply instantiate WriteConcern:

```
    val wc:WriteConcern = WriteConcern
```

I get this error:

```
    not found: type WriteConcern
```

I have `import com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern`  in first lines of my code, why it is not found? How can I instantiate WriteConcen?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `insert` is a curried function with 3 implicit parameters, `dbObjView, concern, encoder` - from the error it looks like `dbObjView: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject` isn't defined.

Comment: Alas, adding `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject` has not helped.

Comment: You probably need to define an `implicit val` of that type, it will then be substituted into the `implicit` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an import for the necessary `implicit` and insert like this:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
mongoColl.insert(rec)
```

On your question about not being able to instantiate `WriteConcern`, it's because there's a class under `com.mongodb` and there's an enum-like object under `com.mongodb.casbah`. This will work:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern
val wc: com.mongodb.WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Normal
```

Comment: No way. When I try to `mongoColl.insert(rec)` I get these errors: 1) No implicit view available from com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject.
2) not enough arguments for method insert: (implicit dbObjView: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject, implicit concern: com.mongodb.WriteConcern, implicit encoder: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBEncoder)com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.WriteResult. Unspecified value parameter dbObjView.

Comment: Adding this import: `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._` will help. Once I added that, It compiled with no errors.